# Elastic: Is it possible to disable fuzziness of certain fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

Here is my query:

```
"multi_match":{  
   "query":"test",
   "fields":[  
      "name^2",
      "sortName^2",
      "externalId",
      "type^0.5"
   ],
   "type":"best_fields",
   "tie_breaker":0.3,
   "minimum_should_match":"30%",
   "fuzziness":"AUTO"
}
```

My goal is to have the fuzziness working on all fields except "externalId". The reason is that it doesn't make sense to the users to find many results when they are searching for a specific ID.

I would assume that if a field is set to 'not_analyzed' it won't apply the fuzziness, but it seems like that's not the case.

Is there a way to specify in the mapping that a field is not candidate for fuzziness?

Comment: There is no way in the mapping to tell that. Fuzziness is applied while querying

Answer (score 2):

As you need to set fuzziness per field, I see 2 ways so far:

- either combine 2 queries with [dis_max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html) or [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query
- use somewhat clumsy `query_string` with [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_fuzziness) set to 0 for `externalId` field. Query may look like:

  ```
  {
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "name:test^2 sortName:test^2 externalId:test~0 type:test^0.5"
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It gives me no results for an exact match. Maybe I'm missing something, can you send a reference for this operator? Google doesn't help much when searching for "~" or for "tilde"

Comment: Yep, my bad, it doesn't work, I've missed smth. Here's reference that I thought about: http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy Searches

Comment: Thanks Slam. I believe "dis_max" will work here, because it should have the same effect of "best_fields" I'm using now. My use-case is more complicated (I posted here a simplified version) and I'm not able to implement it now and test, I'll update again once I tested it.

Comment: @David Did this work for you? My need is exactly as you described in the question.

Comment: @Nick, unfortunately, I haven't had the chance to test it.